# htaccess: Remove parameter from URL

Tags: .htaccess

```
# case: leading and trailing parameters
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)?session=[0-9a-z]+&(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1&%2 [R=301,L]

# case: leading-only, trailing-only or no additional parameters
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)?session=[0-9a-z]+$|^osCsid=[0-9a-z]+&?(.*)$   [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1 [R=301,L]
```

URL is:
https://www.test.com/test/?session=123

Shouldn't this cut off the `?session=123`?

If not, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule to remove a parameter from anywhere in the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?session=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Nice, works. One more thing, ist it possible to remove just if the value of session begins with "\" ? I tried: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?session=\[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$

Comment: Sorry didn't understand. Do you want to remove this parameter only if value starts with a double quote?

Comment: Almost. Want to remove the parameter if value starts with backslash

Comment: You can use: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?session=\\[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]`

Comment: btw your question mentions `session=123` which is not starting with \